# What is the asymptotic form of the spherical Bessel function $j_{n}(x)$ when $n \to \infty$?

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions, distribution-theory

I am trying to find the asymptotics of the spherical Bessel function $j_n(x)$
when $n\to \infty$.

I was able to find something like

$$  j_{n} ( x)  \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}} \delta \left(x - n\right), ~~n\to \infty, $$

where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function.

My questions are as follows,

1. Is this true? And if yes, under what condition does this relation
   hold true and how can one derive it?
2. If it is not true, how can one obtain the correct asymptotic for large values of $n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is
$$
j_n (x) = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2x}}} J_{n + \frac{1}{2}} (x) \sim  \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2x(2n + 1)} }}\left( {\frac{{ex}}{{2n + 1}}} \right)^{n + \frac{1}{2}} \sim
\frac{1}{{2\sqrt 2 n}}\left( {\frac{{ex}}{{2n}}} \right)^n,
$$
as $n\to +\infty$ (cf. http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.19.E1). You can obtain this by noting that for large $n$, the Bessel function is controlled by the leading term of its Taylor series and using Stirling's formula for the gamma function to simplify the result.